# When to use the first and the second derivative when the subject is not as simple as $x$ and $y$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

With questions like, the surface area $A$ [in $\text{cm}^2$] of an expanding sphere of radius $r$ cm is given by $A= 4 \pi r^2$, find the rate of change of the area with respect to the radius at the instant when the radius is $r= 6~\text{cm}$.

Where the subjects are no longer simply $f(x)= y$, how do I know what the first and second derivative represents?

I understand that

- the first derivative represents the gradient, but what does it represent in the context above?
- the second derivative represents the rate of change, rate of change as in the increasing vs decreasing intervals in a function, same question here, what does it represent in the context mentioned above?

Thanks a lot, would appreciate the help. I know people ask very advanced maths questions here but I’m still in high school struggling with simple stuff like this.

If the subjects and context changes again in another question, how do I know what the first and second derivative represents in a specific context?

Comment: Variable names have no special meaning. $A=4\pi r^2$ is the same as $y=f(x)$, where $y$ is replaced with $A$ and $x$ with $r$. So there is nothing really different in this case, from what you already know.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the choice of notation, the first derivative always represents "the rate of change of the function with respect to the variable". So when we have $A = 4 \pi r^2$, the surface area $A$ is being written as a function of the radius $r$ and so the derivative $\frac{dA}{dr}$ is "the rate of change of the surface area with respect to the radius". In other words, when the radius of the balloon is $r\  \mathrm{cm}$, its surface area is equal to $4 \pi r^2 \ \mathrm{cm}^2$ and the area is changing at a rate of $\frac{dA}{dr} = 8 \pi r \ \mathrm{cm}$ (the units come about because we are looking at an area divided by a length, so it's $\frac{\mathrm{cm}^2}{\mathrm{cm}} = \mathrm{cm}$).